# LDAP authentication fail log

Tags: ldap, openldap

why the log say pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure but the login works fine? or can anyone tell me how can I fix this.

```
Jun 27 09:46:31 [localhost] sshd[16341]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.56.1  user=ope_fptsoft01
Jun 27 09:46:31 [localhost] sshd[16341]: Accepted password for ope_fptsoft01 from 192.168.56.1 port 55087 ssh2
Jun 27 09:46:31 [localhost] sshd[16341]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ope_fptsoft01 by (uid=0)
```

My system-auth:

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so
auth        sufficient    pam_ldap.so minimum_uid=1000 use_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_ldap.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_ldap.so minimum_uid=1000 try_first_pass
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     optional      pam_mkhomedir.so umask=0077
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_ldap.so minimum_uid=1000
```

Comment: Rather a question for ServerFault or SuperUser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is:

```
auth sufficient pam_unix.so try_first_pass
auth sufficient pam_ldap.so
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PAM stack configuration lists two different modules to be sufficient for authentication:

```
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so
auth        sufficient    pam_ldap.so minimum_uid=1000 use_first_pass
```

So first the user is tried via *pam_unix.so* which fails because it's likely a remote user in a LDAP user management. So the user probably was successfully authenticated via *pam_ldap.so*.

Normally one would set option `try_first_pass`:

```
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so try_first_pass
auth        sufficient    pam_ldap.so minimum_uid=1000 use_first_pass
```

See also: [pam_unix(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_unix)

Comment: Yes. But I want don't output "pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure" while I login success. Can you help me ?